# How can I check if a product has any variant that is on Sale?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want to check if any variants (not the default variant) have any active sales applied.
How can I do this at a product level when looping through products (think teasers).

Answer (score 1):

So the only way I could seem to make this work was as follows:

```
{% set onSale = product.variants|filter(v => v.onSale())|length %}

{% if onSale %}
   code here for sales badge/message etc
{% endif %}
```

Not sure if there is a more direct method? If there is please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

the following query possibly produce the similar result

```
{% set variantsHasSales = craft.variants()
    .product(product)
    .hasSales(true)
    .all() 
%}
{% if variantsHasSales|length > 0 %}
  code here for sales badge/message etc
{% endif %}
```

reference : https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/products-variants.html#variant-hassales